# should I navigate to localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server when using webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run `webpack-dev-server` the first three lines of console output are:

```
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from ./dist
```

I'm confused by why I should navigate to `localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/`.  In the past I would find my app living at `localhost:8080`.  What is the difference?  What are the pros and cons for with and without the `/webpack-dev-server` path component?  Does it affect hot reloading?

*edit:*

Hot reloading seems to be a feature that is affected by `/webpack-dev-server`.  My browser does not reload using the following config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    // publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running in `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` gives you the Hot reloading as your app is ran in an iframe.

**Hot reloading** simply means you just hit save, and webpack auto-reload your browser!

But you can still use the `http://localhost:8080/` and you'll miss the hot reloading unless you supply the `webpack-dev-server` command with an extra option.

`webpack-dev-server --hot` or `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline` and then you'll still have the hot reloading that webpack offers.

More info see: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Comment: hot reloading does not seem to be working even with the `--hot` option added if i go to `localhost:8080`